# Is it correct, that as a teacher you "give a practical course"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

As far as I know the correct term is "to give a lecture". Is it also the right werb for seminars, courses? In my native language it would be "to hold a seminar" or "to hold a course".

Comment: The usual terms would be 'run a course' or 'offer a course'.

Comment: "Hold a course" implies stubbornly steering your ship in the wrong direction until is runs up on the rocks.  (And "run it's course" is what a case of the flu does.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Edwin already mentioned the usual and more formal term would be to say 'run a course' or 'offering a course'

---

Online [english courses](https://clasesingleskype.com) through skype